# How to access the internet with new usb kali linux live usb persistence

Tags: usb, kali-linux, live-usb, internet

I have set the boolean in `networkmanager.conf` to true but I honestly don't know where to go from here.

I was factory resetting Windows and it got unplugged so I've been trying to connect Linux (which is only on my USB) to the Internet. I have all of the credentials right (I'm using my neighbors WiFi with their consent) so I can plug it in.

Their WiFi is fine (it's what I'm using on my phone and WiFi worked fine on Windows (I just downloaded Kali Linux on USB beforehand).

I have an inet address under `wlan0` from `ifconfig`.

I'd like to know if this is enough info, otherwise just comment and I'll leave more.

Also, i am connected to the wi-fi it gives me bars in top right. Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 0):

In a GUI session, click on the icon with the bars to bring up the network menu. You can configure network connections from that menu.

If you have bars then you are connected to the wifi. It implies that your credentials *for the wifi* are correct.

If you're on a guest network (common in public places such as cafés, hotels, stations, etc.) then the wifi network may be behind a captive portal where you have to log in: until you log in to the portal, you can only connect to the wifi, not to the Internet. With most portals, just type any `http` address in your web browser (e.g. `http://1.1.1.1/`, or `http://example.com`) and you will be redirected to the portal's login page. After you have entered the credentials there, you will have an Internet connection.

Comment: Ik how to login to wi-fi lol. I had to change my ip address for some reason. Its fixed now.